# Сравнение в PHP , sql;

Tags: php, sql

Не понимаю прикола PHP но всё же , сравниваю правильный пароль , и который ввел пользователь , и тут всегда даёт false , не понимаю в чем проблема , решаю вывести эти переменные и тут :

```
"123452111"{"password":"123452111"}
```

в PHP:

```
    $password = $_POST["passworded"];
    $sqlch = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE login = '$login'";
    $resch = mysqli_query($mysql_con, $sqlch);
    $rowch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resch);
    if ($rowch != $password) {
    echo json_encode($password);
    echo json_encode($rowch);
    setcookie("login", $login, time()+3600*24*30, "/"); 
    } else {
        echo json_encode("3");
    }
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc` возвращает ассоциативный массив, внимательнее читайте документацию. Сравнивайте значение `$rowch['password']`. Обратите внимание, что хранить пароль в базе небезапасно.

Comment: А где его хранить ?

Comment: Храните солёный хэш. Подробнее об этом можно почитать в интернете погуглив "хранение пароля в базе", "хэширование пароля" и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы сравнивание массив со строкой, поэтому на выходе и получается false.

mysqli_fetch_assoc возвращает ассоциативный массив даже, если Вы запрашиваете только один столбец.

Верный вариант:

```
$rowch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resch)['password'];
```